# How to send frame buffer to surfaceflinger in android?

Tags: java, android, vnc-server

I am developing an app in which I want to send some frames from a remote device to a client android device.

I referred to this project: [droidVncServer](https://github.com/oNaiPs/droid-VNC-server)

I can't figure out how they are sending frames from the server to the client and then display it on the client device using surface flinger .

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use cmd `adb shell screencap` and send frames either in png format or in byte stream to the client android device.

Not an answer to your question, but may be an solution for your problem.